# Playing recordings from a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I have a custom adapter which in its constructor I set up a new `MediaPlayer` instance

```
  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC );
  mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener( this );
  mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener( this );
  mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener( this );
   int volume = getAudioStreamVolume(context);
   int maxVol = getMaxAudioStreamVolume( context );
  mMediaPlayer.setVolume( (float)volume/maxVol, (float)volume/maxVol);
```

For each row item I have a button to play the audio set up as below, the file path is passed from a list and I have `Log` that value to verify there is actually a path string

```
 holder.playAudio.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {                 
                setupMediaPlayer( path );

            }
        } );
```

The method to setupMediaPlayer

```
private void setupMediaPlayer( String filePath ) {
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC );

        Log.e( getClass().getName(), filePath );
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource( filePath );
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
   }}
```

I actually attempt to play the sound in the implemented onPreparedListener of my adapter class. My issue is that from the listview only some of the recordings are being played, when I attempt to press the play button on the others I get this error in LogCat

`E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-19, 0)`

In my OnErrorListener I have the following

`Log.e( getClass().getName(), "MP ERROR "+ what + " ERROR CODE "+errorExtra );` 
and that results in

```
MP ERROR -19 ERROR CODE 0
```

I am not sure why only some of the files are being played while most of the others are not, also I have checked file explorer and the files are in the correct location.